# Firebase cloud function https.onRequest inside a wrapper function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase cloud functions (node.js) for my app and I want to create a shared wrapper for all of my endpoints that will handle errors and have some checks.

Is it possible to create a wrapper function for the cloud functions and then expose it as a new endpoint?

Example:

```
// normal function that works
const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    functions.logger.log("hello world!");
    return res.end();
})

// the wrapper function that handles errors and shared logic
const functionsWrapper = async ({allowedMethods, handler}) =>
    functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
            try {
                if (allowedMethods) {
                    if (!allowedMethods.includes(req.method.toLowerCase())) {
                        return res.status(405).end();
                    }
                }
                const result = await handler;
                return res.json(result);
            } catch (error) {
                //handling errors here
            }
        }
    );

// the function I want to wrap and then expose as an endpoint
const anotherFunc = functionsWrapper({
    allowedMethods: ['get'],
    async handler() {
        return {message: 'I am inside functionsWrapper'}
    }
})

// exposing the functions
module.exports = {
    helloWorld, // helloWorld can be called and gets an endpoint
    anotherFunc // anotherFunc does not get an endpoint
}
```

I think that Firebase finds where functions.https.onRequest is being exported and then exposes it as an endpoint but how can I expose 'anotherFunc'?

Or in short how to expose:

```
const endpoint = () => functions.htpps.onRequest((req, res) => {})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if this would be applicable? [Organize multiple functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions)

Comment: @RobertG unfortunately not there is nothing about it there